# How to insert a cart slidetoggle option when cart icon is clicked?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, onclick, shopping-cart

Im trying to work on my Ecommerce website. [www.serendib-batik.com](http://www.serendib-batik.com)

I already have a plugin that opens a "Slidein Cart" when a customer adds items to cart.

What I want is to open the sliding cart when someone clicks the cart icon in the top menu . I tried adding code to slide in cart from right to left but it isn't working. Below is my code .

```
(function(){

$(".fa fa-shopping-cart").on("click", function() {
$(".xoo-wsc-modal").slideToggle( "slow");
});

})();
```

It doesn't work for me. Maybe im missing some start and end function codes to run this. or my css is wrong.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is located that code ? I mean the jquery you try in your site.

Comment: Above is the code im trying to work on. Damn... should it go to javascript instead of functions.php?

Comment: Depends of how you serving it from php if you have it on, because i don't see where you have that function, can you show me where is stored this script in your site ?

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado When I try to enter it, there is a systax error. Doesn't let me save it.

Comment: What syntax error ? Put it on question or here.

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 8671 of file wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: Put the error line.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: I mean the line what gives that error, not the error.

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado ops.. sry... $(".fa fa-shopping-cart").on("click", function() {

Comment: If you have it on php, how you **echo** this javascript ?

Comment: @AlumnoCabreado Im totally confused now. Trust me... im not much good with codings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233966/discussion-between-alumno-cabreado-and-cheesyblast).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

`$` is undefined in your site `jQuery` is the assumed alias of `$` but that one didn't work, the cause can be a conflict in libraries, use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Example:

```
jQuery(".fa.fa-shopping-cart").on("click", function() {
jQuery(".xoo-wsc-modal").slideToggle( "slow");});
```